# ui-sref-active on an abstract state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have these routes:

- `.account` /:email
- `.account.home` /:email
- `.account.personal` /:email/personal
- `.account.settings` /:email/settings

`.account` is an abstract state and `.account.home` is the default state that it would go onto.

Now if I have this link, with an `ui-sref-active` to add a class when it is navigated, I would do something like

```
<a ui-sref-active='active' ui-sref='.account.home({email: account.email})'></a>
```

the right element is set with an `active` class when it is clicked (which is was expected), but if I then clicked on `.account.personal` it is removed since it is not a child of `.account.home` but a child of `.account`

How can I set the `ui-sref-active` to remain active to the `<a></a>` above even I selected a different route under it? But I cannot link it to the abstract state since we cannot navigate to an abstract state?

Comment: You can achive this using `ng-class` and use the https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location link to know more about the location and check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Xu163MMzio&list=PLZm85UZQLd2SFY1lOEUNgplCyFpAQGo9D for more understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `ui-sref-active` like `ng-class`

```
<a 
    ui-sref-active='{"active": ".account({email: account.email})" }' 
    ui-sref='.account.home({email: account.email})'
>
```

the important part is this:

`{"active": ".account({email: account.email})" }`

which tells ui-router to set the `active` class when the current state is `.account({email: account.email})` so it is now looking at the abstract state `.account` and not `.account.home`