# Click on any ui-sref on dashboard show li active in ul li

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dashboard where dashboard is abstract state and subdashboard is the very next child state for the dashboard.

[image]

Here view details of users use to go to state dashboard.tables. But the problem is that, the html element li is not opening / getting active.

[image]

Though the state is changed, that particular element is not getting active which is under datatables

[image]

In the above image, I have done manually open to just illustrate my query.
That is click / change of any state should be get active in the side menu and show as active. Any help will be great

Here is my code,

```
<li class="has_sub">
<a href="" class="waves-effect waves-light"><i class="md md-view-list"></i><span> Data Tables </span><span class="pull-right"><i class="md md-add"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li ui-sref-active='{"active": "dashboard" }' ><a ui-sref="dashboard.tables">Tables</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Here are my routes

```
  r.state("dashboard",{abstract:"true",templateUrl:"partials/dashboard.html"})
  r.state("dashboard.subdashboard",{url:"/dashboard",templateUrl:"partials/subdashboard.html"})
  r.state("dashboard.tables",{url:"/tables",templateUrl:"partials/tables.html"});
```

Also as said by LouieAlmeda I have written, but as it wont work i removed it.
and also ng-class i have tested but no use

Comment: Though its a duplicate question, many of them is not able to solve this as there is various methods to do. try this ng-class="{active: $state.includes('nameofyourstate)}" to your li

Comment: Thanks @NitinAgarwal for your soon response. Yes i also tried that ng-class, ui-sref-active, assign the value to $scope.$state=$state in controller and $rootscope.$state=$state in run but no use. Any help will be great

Comment: I had a similar question with a solution regarding adding a class on an abstract state: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091312/ui-sref-active-on-an-abstract-state

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @LouieAlmeda. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show your code in a fiddle or SO snippet?

Comment: Can you add your `routes` as well please

Comment: Again i have edited. Now let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<li ui-sref-active='{"active": ".dashboard" }' ><a ui-sref="dashboard.tables">Tables</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks @Louie Almeda. Already i have tried with that but it not worked for me.